# How can I locate a specific type in an Assembly *efficiently*?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, types

I'm looking for a more efficient way to find a type in an Assembly that derives from a known specific type. Basically, I have a plugin architecture in my application, and for the longest time we've been doing this:

```
For Each t As Type In assem.GetTypes()
    If t.BaseType Is pluginType Then
        'Do Stuff here'
    End If
Next
```

Some of the plugins have a large number of types and we're starting to see this take a few seconds. Is there any way I can just ask for all types that have a BaseType of "pluginType"?

EDIT:
I over-simplified my code sample. I was using .GetExportedTypes() in my actual code. However, I alot of classes were marked as Public, so it wasn't helping too much. I combed through the projects and marked everything "Friend" except for the actual plugin class, and it still takes nearly the same amount of time to examine the assemblies. I cut maybe 100 ms off of 1.3 seconds (which is less than 10%). Is this just the minimum time I have to deal with? I'd also tried the Assembly Attribute suggestion and it still didn't yield much difference (maybe 100ms again). Is the rest of the time the overhead I have to pay to load assemblies dynamically?

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but perhaps have a look at MEF: http://www.codeplex.com/MEF

Comment: How much more complex is your real test condition? Are you using `AndAlso` and `OrElse` or just `And` and `Or`? I ask because on my slowest machine, using the DotLisp interpreter, enumerating 14807 types takes 0.322 seconds and getting public types with `BaseType = Component` takes 0.458 seconds. Oh, in checking the compiled LinqPad version of this query on this slower machine I see the problem: before the `Type` objects are cached, or even built behind the scenes, it's much slower: 10961 `Types` enumerated in 10.206 seconds! Immediately after, it's only 0.03323 seconds to find `Components`.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you may try using `GetExportedTypes()` to narrow down the list of potential types. Other than that, there's no way you can speed up the iteration process. You can, however, include a plugin mainfest which would specify the exact type (types) of plugins within a particular assembly:

```
<manifest>
    <plugin type="FooBar.Plugins.BazPlugin, FooBar" />
</manifest>
```

so that you'd be able to do `Type.GetType(string)`

```
IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)Type.GetType("manifest/plugin/@type" /* for the sake of this discussion */);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.GetExportedTypes() only returns public classes. Could this help?

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [mono-devel mailing list post by Jonathan Pryor](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2009-December/033691.html) and [Plug-in Framework (Part1): Marking Types for Consumption](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/articles/61042.aspx) : **use assembly-level attributes**.

In short, you'd add a new attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple=true)]
class PluginAttribute : Attribute {
  public PluginAttribute (Type type) {this.Type = type;}
  public Type Type {get; private set;}
}
```

Then specify this attribute at the assembly level:

```
[assembly:Plugin (typeof(Plugin1))]
[assembly:Plugin (typeof(Plugin2))]
```

Then query the assembly for all the PluginAttributes:

```
Assembly a = ...;
PluginAttribute[] plugins =
    (PluginAttribute[]) a.GetCustomAttributes (
        typeof(PluginAttribute), true);
foreach (var plugin in plugins)
// plugin.Type is the type to use as a plugin
```

This can be significantly faster than using `Assembly.GetTypes()` / `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()`, as only
the types which are listed in `[assembly:Plugin]` attributes actually need
to be loaded, which can significantly decrease the amount of memory
consumed (depending on the number of types in the assembly).

Answer (score 0):

Our plug-in system utilises attributes to identify the plug-in types. We then just scan the assembly for the specific attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Given my comment on the question, if you can, enumerate all the types on another thread while doing other things. Then, when you're ready to enumerate the types you need, it should be at least two orders of magnitude faster, according to [my tests](http://share.linqpad.net/k3ffxb.linq).